# get json object without array name in android 2

Tags: android, json

I've json like this

```
array (
  'status' => 'OK',
  'categories' => 
  array (
    'Sepeda' => 
    array (
      83 => 'Sepeda MTB',
      'Fullbike' => 
      array (
        370 => 'MTB',
        371 => 'Roadbike',
        374 => 'Fixie',
        375 => 'Sepeda Lipat',
        378 => 'City Bike',
        380 => 'BMX',
        382 => 'Onthel',
      ),
```

that I wanna ask , how code to get "Fullbike" ?? thanks for your advice , really need help , thanks

Comment: That's not json. That's php.

Comment: Do you mean after json_encode? You mean you want to get "Fullbike" using position? or get The Json Array without using "Fullbike" ??

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the PHP docs to get your array to JSON: [PHP:json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Alternatively, could parse the PHP array as it is, but that doesn't sound like fun.

Second checkout the [Android JSON handling docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to see how to process JSON with Android. That's best done with `JSONObject`

Here's an example

```
String getJsonThingy(String rawJson) {
String strFullBike = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(rawJson);
            JSONObject jsonCategories = json.getJSONObject("categories");
            JSONObject jsonSepeda = jsonCategories.getJSONObject("Sepeda");
            strFullBike = jsonSepeda.getString("Fullbike");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strFullBike;
```

I'd like to point out that this code isn't what you want your final product to look like -- **it's a start.**

Also, check out these related SO questions to help you get a better idea of what you should be looking for.

- [Android create a JSON array of JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526376/android-create-a-json-array-of-json-objects)
- [Parsing nested JSON object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986123/parsing-nested-json-object-in-android)
- [How to Parse a JSON Object In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566669/how-to-parse-a-json-object-in-android)

Final note: It may not be a bad idea for your Android client to ask your server for specific parts of your array, as seeing how your array is nested.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     //get Full Bike Json object first
     JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("categories").getJSONObject("Sepeda").getJSONObject("Fullbike");
     //Get inner values like this now
      String mtb = jsonObject.getString("370");
      Log.e("Response", mtb);           
} catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```