# Android - how to format objects in JSON

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have this class:

```
    class Type{
        public int id;
        public String name;
    }
```

and I want to format object in JSON this way

```
    {[1,"superMarket"],[2,"restaurant "]}
```

and also put data from JSON to "Type" object

can some one help me please......

Comment: Have a look to GSON, they have a lot of examples showing what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an easy to understand example for encoding and parsing json:

**[Android JSON Tutorial: Create and Parse JSON data](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html)**

and

**[JSON in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)**

Answer (score 0):

you nee to use a jasonArray and thee jsonObject ro do this..
you can viw this answer

[Android create a JSON array of JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526376/android-create-a-json-array-of-json-objects)

Answer (score 0):

**Type to JSON**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.putString("id", id);
jsonObj.putString("name", name);
```

You can add as many `jsonObj`s to JSONArray.

**JSON to Type**

```
Type type = new Type();
type.setId(jsonObj.optString("id"));
type.setName(jsonObj.optString("name"));
```